# Apparent singularity of Magnetic field generator by a ♾️ conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electric-current, singularities

Let's assume two perpendicular wires: one is infinitely long and the other's length is $l$ (finite).

The second wire is placed vertically on top of the infinitely long wire and there is a distance of d between the two perpendicular wires carrying current $I_1$ and $I_2$.

Finding total force is easy by simple integration but my question is:

If distance $d = 0$, then force $F = \infty$, how's this possible? I heard someone talking about cases where a violation of Newton's law occurs, please clarify how.

[image: position of two wires][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9rES.jpg)

Comment: Possible violations of Newton's third law are separate from the first question. You should look at previous Q&A on such a theme and ask a new question if there is something you feel has not been addressed satisfactorily.

Comment: Please give your post a descriptive title that describes the conceptual question you're asking about - so that future users can find it via search.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking at is not a problem of the Force, but rather something more fundamental: the very magnetic field generated by the infinite wire presents a singularity at $d=0$, which is why you seem to get an infinite force and deduce "Newton's laws are broken". They are not. Let me show you how it works, firstly quantitatively and then qualitatively.

According to Ampère's law, you can find the magnetic field generated by a body **approximately** through:

$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=\mu\cdot I$$

From this expression you can easily obtain the infinite wire's magnetic field assuming B is constant at a given distance from said wire and therefore doing:

$$B = \frac{\mu\cdot I}{\oint d\vec{l}}=\frac{\mu I}{2\pi d}$$

As you can see, the magnetic field *per se* presents a singularity at $d=0$. This is why you get a singularity when calculating the force, too. Now let's understand the physical meaning of said singularity.

The integral used in Ampère's law is a path integral, which means you are "walking through a one dimensional path". For instance, in this case you are walking all your way around a closed circumference. Therefore, the limiting case is when $d=0$, as you are now in the "core" of the wire, through where charges are flowing. Nonetheless, since you are at radius $d=0$ and you assume your wire to have no volume at all, your charges are confined to said one dimensional space and therefore if you consider $d=0$ (the centre of the wire) you are not considering any charges at all. You are, let us say, traveling along with the charges, and therefore you cannot experience an external magnetic field if you yourself are moving along the wire with the charges.

To clarify, no Newton's laws are broken here. Your confusion arises, as they often do, from a mathematical consideration regarding an approximation. If you consider the wire to have volume, you can work your way around this problem.